# 'AnyObject' is not convertible to 'String' while unwrapping optional

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

The code below is giving me the error " 'AnyObject' is not convertible to 'String' " at the line where I put my "if let" statement to unwrap the optional productData pulled from Parse. I'm just trying to pull a String from an object in Parse. I've checked everywhere and all the standard answers/solutions aren't working. Any thoughts?

Most of this code is taken straight from the Parse iOS docs [Here](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/guide)

```
import Foundation

import Parse

func getDataFromParse () {

var productDataFromParse = PFQuery(className:"Product")

productDataFromParse.getObjectInBackgroundWithId("uyeXHufDgq") {

(productData: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

if error == nil && productData != nil {

    if let productTitle = productData["productTitle"] as! String {
        self.productTitle = productTitle
    }


} else {
    println(error)
}
}

}
```

Comment: Was your problem solved or do you have more questions? If it has, please select one of the answers. If not, let me know and I'll try to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`productData: PFObject?` object is an optional itself. You can't subscript over it yet, because it needs to be unwrapped before. You can replace the `productData != nil` check with optional chaining.

In Swift 1.2 you can do that and your error checking in the same statement:

```
if let productTitle = productData?["productTitle"] as? String
   where error == nil {
    self.productTitle = productTitle
}
```

*Note the additional `?` between the `productData` and the square brackets.*